# How to keep website(www) parked at GoDaddy but manage e-mails elsewhere?

Tags: web-hosting, email, godaddy, mx

I have a domain registered at GoDaddy and a dedicated server I want to use to manage e-mails.

If I want to keep www.mydomain.com loading from GoDaddy(at least for now) yet when e-mails are sent to mymailbox@mydomain.com these are managed over at my dedicated server, do I simply have to add a new Hostname in the GoDaddy control panel like this:

Hostname: MAIL

IP Address: IP of the dedicated server

Would this be enough, or I also need to add an MX record and if yes, how?

In my dedicated server control panel, I added this for the domain:

Existing DNS records

```
Hostname: @
Type: MX
Content: mail.mydomain.com
Priority: 0
Time to live: 300
```

Comment: Thank you John. Just one small note, what I needed is actually the other way round so the answer would be:
Point the domain's MX records to your server.
Point the domain's A or CNAME records to GoDaddy

Comment: Did the linked question answer your question adequately?

Comment: Hi Dan - Yes, I managed to achieve what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: NP, glad to hear that.